# Find values in a second column for identical values in the first, and paste in third column

Tags: r

I have data example data as follows:

```
library(data.table)
dat <- fread("Survey Question_unique Question_all
                   A               1            2
                   B               2            2
                   C               3            2
                   C               5           NA
                   A               7           NA
                   B               6            1
                   A               4            1")
```

I created a common question id `Question_all` to see which questions can be found in multiple surveys (column `Survey`).
I would like to add a column to the data (`found_in`) that shows in which surveys they can be found.

Desired output:

```
library(data.table)
dat <- fread("Survey Question_unique Question_all found_in
                   A               1            2    A, B, C
                   B               2            2    A, B, C
                   C               3            2    A, B, C
                   C               5           NA    NA
                   A               7           NA    NA
                   B               6            1    A, B
                   A               4            1    A, B")
```

How should I accomplish this?

Comment: `dat[, found_in := replace(toString(Survey), is.na(Question_all), NA), 'Question_all']`...Not tested

Comment: Tested and approved

Comment: Seems a misunderstanding.  `found_in` indicates the surveys that contain the number of `question_all` questions ie surveys `A,B` and `C` each contain 2 questions.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to solve your problem:

```
dat[!is.na(Question_all), found_in := toString(sort(Survey)), by=Question_all]

   Survey Question_unique Question_all found_in
1:      A               1            2  A, B, C
2:      B               2            2  A, B, C
3:      C               3            2  A, B, C
4:      C               5           NA     <NA>
5:      A               7           NA     <NA>
6:      B               6            1     A, B
7:      A               4            1     A, B
```